# Accessing property from COM object XML Result Set in SSIS Script Task

Tags: ssis

I am working with an SSIS package that was given. to me. I need to extract XML data from an SSIS variable, but I cannot find a way to do it.

When I hit a breakpoint during runtime in my Script Task, I can hover over the Value property of the variable. This shows me a COM object. When I expand the COM object to view its properties, I see the XML data I need in a property called "xml". How do I get at this property from code?

```
var xmldata = Dts.Variables["User::MyVariableName"].Value;
//xmldata is a COM object with no properties available at design time
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Writing the value out to a file based on examples I have seen online.
  This just writes "System.__ComObject" to the file
- Casting the COM object to a MarshalByRefObject. This didn't give me
  anymore options for retrieving properties
- Setting the COM object to a "dynamic" variable. This gave me a
  compile time error
- Reflection over the COM object to get its properties
  (GetProperties()). The COM object did not support this, so I got back
  an 0 length array
- Changing the result set from XML to DataSet and filling a DataTable
  object. I got back a DataTable with one column and multiple rows of
  "System.Byte[]", which is worthless.

None of these things have been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It looks like I gave up on using "dynamic" too early.

Make sure you add a reference to "Microsoft.CSharp", then do something like the code below:

```
var data = Dts.Variables["User::MyVariableName"]; //Assuming not null. 
var comObject = ((dynamic)data.value);
var propertyValue = comObject.PropertyYouNeed;
```

Make sure the property you are retrieving from the COM object is spelled correctly. A misspelling will not be caught until run time.